# Drupal 6.17 just showing admin blocks

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-themes

I am using Drupal version 6.17 with RootCandy Dark 6.x-1.8 as the administration theme what happens is that Drupal shows the rootcandy regions on the blocks page even if I click on the site's theme. If I disable the administration theme everything works.

I already tried to clear all the caches and nothing changes.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

**Update:** This seams to be a problem with Drupal 6.17 because I changed the administration theme to Garland and other themes and the same problem occurred.

**Update 2:** I having the same problem related here http://drupal.org/node/783892#comment-3111218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Berkes, yesterday a friend of mine found the problem and it was exactly what you said. The problem was that I was using Region Manager 6.x-1.0. After disabling it the regions appeared correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the theme? Drupal allows a not-enabled theme to be used as admin theme, but that often brings problems. You can check it as "enabled" under "Admin » Site Building » Themes"

Comment: berkes, yes the theme is enabled.

Comment: Do you have any module that alters the theme behaviour enabled? Does the problem occur on a vanilla install as well?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but it was being caused by jQuery UI Account Dialogs 6.x-1.0. Disabling that module fixed it. As berkes says, disabling modules that are affecting theme behavior in unique ways seems to solve this.